# Change physical position of view when using animation

Tags: android, animation

I animate my view that I use like button, I slide it up and stop here using `slideUpIn.setFillAfter(true);` But the physical position of the view doesn't change, only appearance. So I have to click in the old position to make a click. Is there any workout around it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set new `LayoutParams` to view with correct position.

Just get `LayoutParams` of view before animation. Then animated. Then add to `LayoutParams` edited by animation fields ant set this new `LayoutParams` to view.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing an AnimationListener and call

```
view.clearAnimation()
```

on the view in

```
onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
```